# Sliding a div from right > to left <

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching for a code snippet that I assumed would already be out there somwhere. There are many different variations that I have found but none of which are best suited for me. I have attempted to modify jsfiddles ive found and tweak other examples but to no avail.

As I have little to no prior experience with javascript and Jquery languages I hoped someone on here could help.

In my current project I have a single page in which all the content is loaded. currently I have six divs all hidden off screen to the right. with a vertical navigation menu sitting on the left. What I want is for when a link with the assigned div is clicked, that targeted div slides on screen from right to left and stops next to the navigation menu.

The twist, however is when a new link is clicked the content of the previous div to slide off screen allowing the newely selected div to replace it.

Hopefully I have explained myself well enough.

The content divs I want slided are =

id="content-one"

id="content-two"

and so on.

Any solutions or pointers in the right direction would be extreamly usefull many thanks in advance.

This is what i was originally trying to modify but i was unsuccessful...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navigation li a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();`enter code here`
    var hrefval = $(this).attr("href");

    if(hrefval == "#content-one") {
      var distance = $('#container').css('right');

      if(distance == "auto" || distance == "0px") {
        $(this).addClass("open");
        activateSlider();
      } else {
        deactivateSlider();
      }
    }
  }); // end click event handler

 // $("#closebtn").on("click", function(e){
//    e.preventDefault();
//    closeSidepage();
//  }); // end close button event handler

  function activateSlider() {
    $('#container').animate({
      right: '350px'
    }, 400, 'easeOutBack'); 
  }

  function deactivateSlider(){
    $("#navigation li a").removeClass("open");
    $('#container').animate({
      right: '0px'
    }, 400, 'easeOutQuint');  
  }
});
```

Comment: look at the [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) property of jquery. You could simply animate the right property. *First let us see you've tryed something*

Comment: That is what I had tried. It seemed simple enough at the time, however I dont understand the code all to well.

Comment: I recommend you to follow a tuturiol instead of taking a snippet of somebody else, goodluck :)

Comment: checkout .slideToggle(), animate or use css3 for transition and then .toggleClass() - but in the end i must agree with @nkmol if you dont understand it go for tutorial and learn simple stuff like how varables work, what a method is, the difference between objects & arrays - how to use an if or an switch statement ofc you have to know about boolean - after that watch a few videos with douglas crockford to understand why all this is necessary

Comment: you can try this tutorial for better result

http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

Here `.panel` your sliding `div` `class`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeU3U/6/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var settings = {
    objSlideTrigger: '#trigger', // link button id
    objSlidePanel: '.panel' // slide div class or id
  }

  $(settings.objSlideTrigger).on('click', function() {
    //If the panel isn't out
    if (!$(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {
      slidePanelOut();
    } else if ($(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {
      slidePanelIn();
    }
  });

  function slidePanelOut() {
    //Animate it to left 
    $(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
      'right': '-67%'
    });
    //Add the out class
    $(settings.objSlidePanel).addClass('out');
  }

  function slidePanelIn() {
    //Otherwise, animate it back in
    $(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
      'right': '-89%'
    });
    //Remove the out class
    $(settings.objSlidePanel).removeClass('out');
  }

});
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 85%;
  padding: 2%;
  position: fixed;
  right: -89%;
  top: 46px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.trigger {
  width: 8%;
  text-align: center;
  color: goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  padding: 0.5% 0%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background: #2F2F2F;
  right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel" class="panel">
  <!-- Trigger -->content
</div>
<a id="trigger" class="trigger">click here</a>
```

Comment: Slight problem, it appears to be jammed I click the button an the div just jiggles right then left quickly about 2 px then stops.. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you! I have it working to a point. Its sliding and everything. But for some reason it will not stay open. (I.e. i click the button it startes sliding but quickly closes.) I think it may be because of additional Css linked with the content boxes. Ill have a tinker and see if I cannot resolve it. Thank you for your help all. Much appreciated!

Comment: Heads up, I did fix it in the end, it was infact an additional acting css element. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there any way I could create multiple links with content boxes ? I have been trying for a few days now, cant seem to nail it :?